# How to migrate Python packages from Nexus to Azure DevOps

Tags: python, migration, nexus3, azure-artifacts

We are migrating from Sonatype Nexus to Azure Artifacts. There are 100s of python packages on Nexus currently. All of which are needed in Azure. Is there a way to upload/sync them to Azure?

I have successfully uploaded one package of a specific version by creating a dist, using twine & .pypirc file.
Like so `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel && twine upload -r project-name dist/*`
But it is not feasible to do that manually on all packages & their different versions.

Please help with any scripts or migration tools that you might know of.

We use Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.19.1-01.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to migrate Python packages from Nexus to Azure DevOps

Currently, Azure devops only provide the AzureArtifactsPackageMigration PowerShell module, you can easily migrate your **NuGet** packages from **MyGet**. **Future development will support migration from other packaging solutions and package types**.

Reference the document [Migrate your packages to Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/migrate-packages?view=azure-devops).

For the Python packages from Nexus, there is a Bash script to migrate from Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager OSS to Azure DevOps Artifacts, you could check if it help you:

[nexus2artifacts](https://github.com/mdgomes/nexus2artifacts)

Comment: Will update info on whether the nexus2artifacts script helped. Thanks!

Comment: did it work for you for python?